# Angular same component instance to the same application multiple times in hierarchy thru modal

Tags: angular

I have an application with componentA( with selector 'dyn-form') that generates dynamic form. I have used to create the form page...In this form page, on the click of a button, I load a dynamic component within the modal. Since this also needs a form, I have used the same selector 'dyn-form' to load the componentA again as a child in the hierarchy.

I have found that child ComponentA is replacing the first selector 'dyn-form' and view rendering is happening for the child form replacing the parent form. ( I am expecting it to show up in the modal).

I have simplified the problem above. The real case is more complex loading of form->datagrid(child)->form(in the modal)

Any hints how to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry if i am wrong but for matter of architectur maybe you must use a diferent selector (and a diferent component) event if it has the same properties and html than the other component dyn-form

Comment: Form(html) gets generated dynamically. It's different for each instance of 'dyn-form'. Using different selector is not possible.

Comment: Ok, can you reproduce it in stackblitz? maybe i can check the code online